# How to find missing rows in second table from first table in my case?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I have two tables.

Table1: First

```
--------------------------
|  iso          | WeldNo |
--------------------------
| AMD-11201-01  |     02 |
| RFG-11203-01  |     01 |
| AMD-11201-01  |     03 |
| RFG-11203-01  |     05 |
```

Table2: Second

```
--------------------------
|  iso          | WeldNo |
--------------------------
| AMD-11201-01  |     02 |
| RFG-11203-01  |     01 |
| RFG-11203-01  |     05 |
```

Expected Result:

```
--------------------------
|  iso          | WeldNo |
--------------------------
| AMD-11201-01  |     03 |
```

i tried query but wont work

```
select a.iso, a.WeldNo 
from first a 
where a.WeldNo, a.iso not in (select b.iso,b.WeldNo from second b);
```

Kindly give solution to my scenario

Comment: So are you using MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: You query is almost ready. Fix it with `.. where (a.iso, a.WeldNo) not in ..` (This is for MySQL. Don't know if it works on sql-server).

Comment: I second dotnetom's question. What are you ask for general SQL, MySQL or SQL Server? You really shouldn't be tagging both mysql and sql-server at the same time unless you are talking about the porting a database between them or something.  So if it's general SQL, drop both MySQL and  sql-server. If it about a specific database pick that.

Answer (score 2):

From the tags on the question it is not clear which RDBMS you are using. If you are using SQL Server you can use [`EXCEPT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx):

```
select a.iso, a.WeldNo 
from first a 

EXCEPT

select b.iso, b.WeldNo 
from second b
```

This selects all items from the `SELECT` statement, except for the ones that are found in the second `SELECT` statement.

If you are using MySQL you could slightly fix your query (i.e. add parenthesis) and you should get a working query:

```
select a.iso, a.WeldNo 
from first a 
where (a.WeldNo, a.iso) not in (select b.WeldNo, b.iso from second b)
```

Comment: Your column order is differend in the second query. `a.WeldNo, a.iso` and `b.iso,b.WeldNo`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Thanks for noticing, fixed it

Comment: nothing works any query here.

Comment: @user3041016 Do you get an error? Unexpected results? Is something else not working?

Answer (score 1):

```
select f.*
from first_table f
left join second_table s on s.iso = f.iso
                        and s.WeldNo = f.WeldNo 
where s.iso is null
```

Also see [this great explanation of joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use either a `LEFT JOIN` or an `EXCEPT`.

**Left Join:**

```
SELECT t1.iso, t1.WeldNo
FROM Table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.iso = t2.iso AND t1.WeldNo = t2.WeldNo
WHERE t2.iso IS NULL
```

**Except:**

```
SELECT iso, WeldNo
FROM Table1
EXECEPT
SELECT iso, WeldNo
FROM Table2
```

There are some differences, though.  In the case of except, both results have to have the same columns, while the `LEFT JOIN` lets you specify what to select from each table.  Also, in most cases, the `LEFT JOIN` is going to be more performant, as it is better optimized.  However, the `EXCEPT` will only return *unique* rows from the first query that are missing from the second query, so it might be more applicable to the situation.  Of course, you could add a `DISTINCT` To the first query for a similar result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.iso, t1.WeldNo
FROM Table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.iso = t2.iso AND t1.WeldNo = t2.WeldNo
WHERE t2.iso IS NULL
```

All that said, it's probably better to use the `LEFT JOIN`, however it may vary depending on your database.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `not exists` because it expresses the intent clearly i.e. "select all rows from table1 where a row in table2 with the same iso and WeldNo does not exist"

```
select * from table1 t1
where not exists (
    select 1 from table2 t2
    where t2.iso = t1.iso
    and t2.WeldNo = t1.WeldNo
)
```